# Как быть, если старый ответ не соответствует современному положению?

Tags: обсуждение

Копался тут в стареньком и наткнулся на вопрос [Есть ли в Python оператор switch case?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460207/209304). И ответ на него [того же пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460208/209304).

Ответ шикарен, за что, спасибо, [Timofei Bondarev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177596/timofei-bondarev).

Но как и все в жизни не вечно под луной, прошло время и в python таки докинули данную конструкцию. Хотя ниже [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265114/209304) и описывает новую функциональность, он не привлекает столько внимания, а самый оцененный ответ теперь не отражает всю реальность, хотя и остается более чем актуальным.

Вопрос: есть ли функционал для объединения ответов внутри *ruSO*? Да, и есть, ли, смысл во всем этом?

Понимаю, что внесение правки в ответ, это не верный путь и есть неуважение к автору.

**UPD**

Хороший и полный ответ - то зачем сюда приходят. Не все, конечно. В данном случае ответ данный Timofei исчерпывающий и полный, до момента релиза версии 3.10. Ко всему прочему ответ объемен и не каждый его дочитает до конца и еще меньше, кто обратит внимание на другие ответы. Так вот, ответ актуален на сегодняшний день для версий ниже 3.10, но он не верен для новой версии. Но в тот же момент, те решения которые указаны имеют место быть и в новой версии. Объединение или дополнение, в моем мозгу, это либо дополнить сам ответ (с пометкой почему), либо в самом верху ответа перенапаравить на ответ для новой версии python

Comment: Можно добавить дисклеймер "ответ актуален до такой-то версии, для новых версий - обратите внимание на другие ответы"

Comment: Уточните, что такое *"объединение ответов"* и зачем оно нужно в данном случае?

Comment: @Kromster дополнил ответ

Comment: Попробуйте просто сделать правку к ответу - "Ответ дан для версий до 3.10. В новых версиях switch case есть (см. ссылка)"

Comment: "Понимаю, что внесение правки в ответ, это не верный путь и есть неуважение к автору." --- как написали выше, достаточно внести правку с отсылкой к версии.

Comment: Объединение ответов можно не делать, достаточно дать ещё один ответ в "горячей теме" где упомянуть о новых современных стандартах или решениях. Оч. часто так и делают. Например в JS пишут, что в ES2015 например появилась такой способ, или в PHP8. можно решить вопрос вот так-то

Comment: Есть соответствующее [обсуждение на MetaSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/3240681).